# STR_TO_DATE can't work with generated TIME formats and values needs to be entered manually, only generated DATATIME and DATE formats work

Tags: mysql, function, datetime, time, temporal

Here I have date1 and time1 as -

```
SELECT @date1;
+----------+
| @date1   |
+----------+
| %D %b %Y |
+----------+
```

```
SELECT @time1;
+--------------------+
| @time1             |
+--------------------+
| %Ih : %im : %ss %p |
+--------------------+
```

Now, I have the following valid queries -

```
SELECT NOW(6) AS output1, DATE_FORMAT(NOW(6), @date1) AS output2, STR_TO_DATE(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(6), @date1), @date1) AS output3;
+----------------------------+---------------+----------------------------+
| output1                    | output2       | output3                    |
+----------------------------+---------------+----------------------------+
| 2021-12-27 02:08:18.282722 | 27th Dec 2021 | 2021-12-27 00:00:00.000000 |
+----------------------------+---------------+----------------------------+
```

```
SELECT NOW(6) AS output1, DATE_FORMAT(NOW(6), CONCAT_WS(SPACE(2), @date1, @time1)) AS output2, STR_TO_DATE(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(6), CONCAT_WS(SPACE(2), @date1, @time1)), CONCAT_WS(SPACE(2), @date1, @time1)) AS output3;
+----------------------------+-----------------------------------+----------------------------+
| output1                    | output2                           | output3                    |
+----------------------------+-----------------------------------+----------------------------+
| 2021-12-27 02:12:48.713278 | 27th Dec 2021  02h : 12m : 48s AM | 2021-12-27 02:12:48.000000 |
+----------------------------+-----------------------------------+----------------------------+
```

Now I try the following -

```
SELECT NOW(6) AS output1, DATE_FORMAT(NOW(6), @time1) AS output2, STR_TO_DATE(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(6), @time1), @time1) AS output3;
+----------------------------+--------------------+---------+
| output1                    | output2            | output3 |
+----------------------------+--------------------+---------+
| 2021-12-27 02:20:12.335700 | 02h : 20m : 12s AM | NULL    |
+----------------------------+--------------------+---------+
```

```
SELECT CURTIME(6) AS output1, DATE_FORMAT(CURTIME(6), @time1) AS output2, STR_TO_DATE(DATE_FORMAT(CURTIME(6), @time1), @time1) AS output3;
+-----------------+--------------------+---------+
| output1         | output2            | output3 |
+-----------------+--------------------+---------+
| 02:16:53.952314 | 02h : 16m : 53s AM | NULL    |
+-----------------+--------------------+---------+
```

```
SELECT CURTIME(6) AS output1, TIME_FORMAT(CURTIME(6), @time1) AS output2, STR_TO_DATE(TIME_FORMAT(CURTIME(6), @time1), @time1) AS output3;
+-----------------+--------------------+---------+
| output1         | output2            | output3 |
+-----------------+--------------------+---------+
| 02:18:33.676080 | 02h : 18m : 33s AM | NULL    |
+-----------------+--------------------+---------+
```

In all the above cases I get output3 as `NULL`

It seems I can generate the desired result only if I manually enter the values -

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE("02h : 26m : 26s AM", "%Ih : %im : %ss %p") AS output;
+----------+
| output   |
+----------+
| 02:26:26 |
+----------+
```

Even the following query doesn't seem to work -

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE("02h : 26m : 26s AM", @time1) AS output;
+--------+
| output |
+--------+
| NULL   |
+--------+
```

Now, this is strange. If there is any presence of `date` format with or without `time` format, `STR_TO_DATE` works fine with generated values. But if there is only `time` format without any presence of `date` format, `STR_TO_DATE` no longer works with generated values. In such cases `STR_TO_DATE` works only with manually entered values.

This is obviously a huge inconvenience since rarely one only enters values manually and will generally work with generated values in practical applications.

Now there is nothing like `STR_TO_TIME` in MySQL.

So is there any workaround? Or is it that the only way forward is to raise a feature request and wait for a new improved release in future?

---

UPDATE:

Interestingly, the following works perfectly -

```
SELECT NOW(6) AS output1, DATE_FORMAT(NOW(6), GET_FORMAT(TIME, "USA")) AS output2, STR_TO_DATE(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(6), GET_FORMAT(TIME, "USA")), GET_FORMAT(TIME, "USA")) AS output3;
+----------------------------+-------------+----------+
| output1                    | output2     | output3  |
+----------------------------+-------------+----------+
| 2021-12-27 03:26:04.787166 | 03:26:04 AM | 03:26:04 |
+----------------------------+-------------+----------+
```

Comment: It works fine up to version 5.6: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=f2a1faf5f5e8a3d25c0d60caad3bbc23 From version 5.7+ the return value is null: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=f2a1faf5f5e8a3d25c0d60caad3bbc23 This looks like a bug.

Comment: @forpas updated my question with additional interesting observation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've encountered something like this before and it seems like in MySQL v5.7, you can't `STR_TO_DATE` on `time` value alone, you'll need the `date` value as well. This works:

```
SET @time1 = '%Y-%m-%d %Ih : %im : %ss %p';

SELECT TIME(STR_TO_DATE(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(6), @time1), '%Y-%m-%d %Ih : %im : %ss %p'))
```

But since the final output of `STR_TO_DATE()` include date, then the `TIME()` function is necessary to extract the time value only.

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=f713502d8c61ddd64d3615a9d69fc635).

Probably because the function is "named" as `STR_TO_DATE`, it makes no sense to convert the time value only. Which is kind of understandable but quite strange as well because on MySQL 8.0, [it doesn't behave like that](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f713502d8c61ddd64d3615a9d69fc635).

Comment: Thank for your answer, but if you observe carefully, in MySQL 8.0 it also behaves like that. Here, in STR_TO_DATE, instead of passing a variable, you are passing values manually, which is the whole point

Comment: Oh yeah, it does. So silly of me not testing all of your `STR_TO_DATE` variant. I apologize for that. I've tried another method [in this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=dbec67aa1e1aba5b52cba5ee2841756a), can you take a look and see if this is something feasible for your operation?

Comment: here you are casting time from a datetime value, but in your original input variable in STR_TO_DATE , the variable still generates a datetime expression and not ONLY time expression. The point being if this variable generates ONLY time expression that has no datetime in it, STR_TO_DATE fails to work, and in such case you have nothing to work with for a TIME casting

Comment: I see, well on MySQL that sure is the case. Anyway, -I doubt that this has any value to your experiment but- on MariaDB, [all your syntax variant works](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=499005a835998a66056004580534cc1c).

Comment: I am not sure but I found your comments sarcastic

Comment: Well, I suggest you try to read from a different (non-sarcastic) tonal perspective. Honestly, I wasn't being sarcastic.. but I do wonder which part of my comment you think is sarcastic?

Comment: "Oh yeah, it does. So silly of me not testing all of your STR_TO_DATE variant. I apologize for that." - especially this part

Comment: That's a surprise, I thought you're talking about my last comment. In any case, I never intended to make you think that's a sarcasm. It's just as how I say it is. To clarify, it's such a _rookie mistake_ for me not to try all of the method you've posted in your question before posting an answer. I hold on to a principle where when I'm supposed to answer a question, I should cover all the issues present in the question and be prepared for follow-up concerns or even constructive criticisms.